# How to understand this regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

```
var regEx = /[24680]d*[24680]/
```

I came across this in one of the solution for a coding question that requires to return true if adjacent even numbers are found in a string else false.

For example: if string is `f54169jk11`, need to return true as 4 16 are adjacent evens.

Comment: https://regexr.com/3jgpp or https://regex101.com/r/7D0yD2/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pattern `/[24680]d*[24680]/` describe a substring and consists of 3 parts:

1. `[24680]` means that substring begins with one of the digits 2,4,6,8,0
2. `d*` means zero or more character `d`
3. `[24680]` means that substring ends with one of the digits 2,4,6,8,0

Comment: For example : 2111114 (begins with 2, followed by zero or more digits and ends with 4) so this returns true but practically there are no adjacent evens. so answer should be false. Could you please correct me?

Comment: Sorry, I just understood....  2 & 111114 are evens here. Never mind..

Comment: Pattern for even number is `\d*[02468]`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, that is the regex you're looking for :

```
var regEx = /[24680]\d*[24680]/
```

you just forget to escape 'd' to check digit  (equivalent to [0-9])